# RemObjects SDK - how to retrieve client GUID from server when connecting to server?

Tags: delphi, remobjects

Does somebody know how to retrieve client GUID when connecting to server in RemObjects SDK ?
(using SuperTCP/IP protocol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the session ID of the current connection on the server, use [SessionID](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/TROSession_Class#Properties) property:

```
SessionIDString := GUIDToString(Session.SessionID);
```

The Session object is found in the uROSessions unit.

To get the session ID on the client, use [ClientID](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/IROMessage_Interface#Properties) property:

```
SessionIDString := GUIDToString(RemoteService.Message.ClientID);
```

RemoteService is your connection's TRORemoteService object.